# Sort Array of Dates, but if past date drop to bottom of Array Swift

Tags: sorting, date, swift3, nsarray

I need to sort a table by time and day for upcoming events.
I need the nearest future date string at the top descending by the events following. BUT I want to drop past events to the bottom of the array/table, where I will hide the date and time, so the history is shown.

**Its an Array of structs if that makes a difference**

for example :

Event3 - 14:15

Event4 - 15:00

Event5 - 18:03

Event1 -

Event2 -

The following works to order my array, I just want to drop past dates to the bottom

```
newArray = oldArray.sorted(by: {Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: $0.eventTime < Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: $1.eventTime})
```

Comment: As an ugly temp fix I have done this, Im sure there is a more elegant way of doing it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution A: sort, split and combine

```
let now = Date()
let sortedArray = myArray.sorted(by: { $0.startTime < $1.startTime })
var finalArray = sortedArray
if let index = sortedArray.index(where: { $0.startTime > now }) {
    if index > 0 {
        finalArray = Array(sortedArray[index ..< sortedArray.endIndex] + sortedArray[sortedArray.startIndex ... index - 1])
    }
}
```

Solution B (faster): sort by a predicate

```
let now = Date()
let newArray = myArray.sorted(by: {
    if $0.startTime > now {
        if $1.startTime > now {
            return $0.startTime < $1.startTime
        } else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        if $1.startTime > now {
            return false
        } else {
            return $0.startTime < $1.startTime
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temp fix I have done this, Im sure there is a more elegant way of doing it, but it might help someone else until a better solution comes along

```
        let allStartToFin = myArrat.sorted(by: {Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:($0.startTime)!).timeIntervalSinceNow < Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:($1.startTime)!).timeIntervalSinceNow})

        var correctOrder = [Object]()
        var past = [Object]()
        for item in 0...(allStartToFin.count - 1) {
            if (Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((allStartToFin[item].startTime)!))) > Date() {
                correctOrder.append(allStartToFin[item])
            } else {
               past.append(allStartToFin[item])
            }
            if item == (allStartToFin.count - 1) {
                correctOrder = correctOrder + past
                self.finalArray = correctOrder
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```